# why didn't i get frequent flier miles on American Airlines with my Alaskan Airlines flight?

Tags: loyalty-programs, american-airlines, alaska-airlines

Both Alaskian Airlines and American Airlines are part of the Oneworld alliance so I'd expect the frequent flier miles to be linked but they're not.

I found my ticket number on my credit card statement and tried to use that along with my advantage number at https://www.aa.com/forms/request-flight-miles/#!/request but I wasn't able to get credit there either.

Any ideas?

Comment: what was the fare class?

Comment: @littleadv - Business (C) and Business (D)

Comment: Did you properly provide your AA number at time of booking or check-in? Did you try to use Alaska’s site to request the credit?

Comment: @jcaron - I bought the tickets through Expedia and Expedia has my AA number on file. As for using Alaska's site..  https://www.alaskaair.com/content/mileage-plan/how-to-earn-miles/request-credit looks to give you frequent flier credit to their frequent flier mile number - not AA's. I mean, idk how all that works. Like if you frequent flier mile #'ers for every airline in a codeshare alliance can you fill out forms to get frequent flier miles for every frequent flier mile # you have even if they're all for the same flight?

Comment: No, you are correct, you should request the miles from AA’s site, not Alaska’s. What did it tell you when you tried? Did your AA number appear on your ticket, trio summary or boarding pass? How long ago were the flights?

Comment: You might need to contact AA about this, for C/D you should have gotten credit.